# How do solve this problem about sequence in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the following problem:

[image]

Here's the code I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i, j=0;

    for(i=0; i<=2.2; i=i+0.2)
    {
        for (j = 1; j == 1; j=j+0.2)
            {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i >= 2) {
                        printf("I=%.0f J=%.0f\n", i, j);
                        printf("I=%.0f J=%.0f\n", i, j+1);
                        printf("I=%.0f J=%.0f\n", i, j+2);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, j);
                        printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, j+1);
                        printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, j+2);
                    }
                j=j+0.2;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me the right output for `i` but `j` isn't working. How do I properly solve this, and why isn't `j` returning the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for (j = 1; j == 1; j=j+0.2)`, the `j == 1` condition will ensure your inner loop will run only 1 time at most.  Once you increment `j` after the 1st iteration, `j` won't be 1 anymore and the loop will break.

Even if it didn't break, you are incrementing `j` by `0.2` *twice* per loop iteration, so you will be skipping values the output is expected to contain.

I would change the inner loop to `for(int j = 1; j <= 3; ++j)` and then have the body simply output `j+i` 1 time per iteration.

Also, `%f` simply doesn't support the output format you are looking for.  `%.0f` won't output any decimals at all, and `%.1f` will force decimals even for `#.0`. Use `%g` instead, which won't output a `.0` decimal.  Also, `printf()` doesn't support `float` anyway, it expects `double`.

Try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(double i = 0.0; i <= 2.0; i += 0.2)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; ++j)
            printf("I=%g J=%g\n", i, j + i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I=0 J=1
I=0 J=2
I=0 J=3
I=0.2 J=1.2
I=0.2 J=2.2
I=0.2 J=3.2
I=0.4 J=1.4
I=0.4 J=2.4
I=0.4 J=3.4
I=0.6 J=1.6
I=0.6 J=2.6
I=0.6 J=3.6
I=0.8 J=1.8
I=0.8 J=2.8
I=0.8 J=3.8
I=1 J=2
I=1 J=3
I=1 J=4
I=1.2 J=2.2
I=1.2 J=3.2
I=1.2 J=4.2
I=1.4 J=2.4
I=1.4 J=3.4
I=1.4 J=4.4
I=1.6 J=2.6
I=1.6 J=3.6
I=1.6 J=4.6
I=1.8 J=2.8
I=1.8 J=3.8
I=1.8 J=4.8
I=2 J=3
I=2 J=4
I=2 J=5
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/cjqSRq)

Answer (score 2):

You do not actually need the double loop, one is enough:

```
int main()
{
    for(float i=0; i<=2; i += 0.2)
    {
        if(i == 0 || i  == 1 || i == 2){
           printf("I=%d J=%d\n", (int)i, (int)i + 1);
           printf("I=%d J=%d\n", (int)i, (int)i + 2);
           printf("I=%d J=%d\n", (int)i, (int)i + 3);
        }
        else{
           printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, i + 1);
           printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, i + 2);
           printf("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, i + 3);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reality is that I have only one loop because I expanded the number of prints.

Borrowing the idea of `%g` from Remy Lebeau the code can be simplified to:

```
int main(){
    for(double i=0; i<=2; i += 0.2){
       printf("I=%g J=%g\n", i, i + 1);
       printf("I=%g J=%g\n", i, i + 2);
       printf("I=%g J=%g\n", i, i + 3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```